# converting string to boost::date and around

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following date :

```
std::string sdt("2011-01-03");
```

I wrote 2 functions as below and called them using:

```
 date test;
  string_to_date(sdt,test);
  date_to_string(test,sdt);
```

the `string_to_date()` works and it returns 
`2011-Jan-03` as it should
whereas the `date_to_string()`  returns

```
not-a-date-time
```

these are the functions:

```
void string_to_date(const std::string& st, date out)
{
  std::string in=st.substr(0,10);
  date d1(from_simple_string(std::string (in.begin(), in.end())));
  std::cout<<d1;
  out=d1;
}


void date_to_string(date in, const std::string& out)
{

  date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%Y-%m-%d"));
  std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), facet));
  std::cout<<in<<std::endl;

    out=in;//this doesn't work

}
```

Comment: I think you should print `in` instead of `d`, so: `std::cout << in << std::endl;`

Comment: @FlorianSowade, thanks...I edited my post to make the correction. how do I assign the string to out, because I want to return std::string. I printed it only to check the output

Comment: You can't change a reference passed in if it's `const`. I'm referring to `out=in;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void date_to_string(date in, std::string& out)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    date_facet* facet(new date_facet("%Y-%m-%d"));
    str.imbue(std::locale(str.getloc(), facet));
    str << in;

    out = str.str();
}
```

should work. Notice the removed `const` from the `out` parameter. Is there a reason not to simply return the produced string?

Comment: also the `date` parameter should be taken by `const` reference - but that's only a performance enhancement.

Comment: made that fix. I do want to return the produced string, that is the goal.

Comment: @user1155299, is there a particular reason you're taking up an extra parameter for the return?

Comment: @chris, not really, is that inefficient?

Comment: @user1155299, that's the whole point of the return value. It's more natural to write `int x = square (2);` than it is to write `int x; square (2, x);`. Also, this now limits the use of the return as a temporary. For example, the former allows `int x = square (square (2));`.

Comment: @chris,got it.that's a quick fix :-)